Expectation of Random Projection Matrix
Suppose $x_i \sim N(0, I_p)$ for $i\in[n]$ where $n < p$.
Let $X = (x1,...,x_n)^T$
What is $E[X^T(XX^T)^{-1}X]$?
Clearly $(XX^T)^{-1}$ is Wishart. I have only seen Normal Inverse Wishart and not with the additional $X$. I tried the standard rotational arguments.
Just looking for references.
